# Passing multiple parameters to client.PostAsJsonAsync function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I am currently posting to my web api like this:

client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/controller/methodincontroller", listOfProductObject);

I would like to know how in addition to the list of my Product object I can also send an additional string to the method in my controller without making it a property of my Product model.

If this isn't possible I will have to make a Model that has 2 properties for this purpose only:

```
IList<Product> productList
string additionalParam
```

Comment: Can you add another parameter to your controller method?

Comment: Yes for example: public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod(IList<Product> productList, string additionalParam). But how would I fill this param from my other application when calling PostAsJsonAsync.

Comment: you could append one to the URI ie `api/controller?additionalParam=something` and the other using from body attribute. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api, so it would look like: `client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/controller/methodincontroller?additionalParam=" + myParam, listOfProductObject);`

Comment: So on the receiving end how would my method declaration look? Which param comes first and do I have to change any of my route settings?

Comment: See below, note that I am not using `PostAsJsonAsync`, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I got a sample working without using `PostAsJsonAsync`:

The setup:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<somemodel> { new somemodel() });
StringContent sc = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpClient c = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
var x = c.PostAsync("http://localhost:58893/api/values?additionalParam=" + "test", sc).Result; // returns 200
```

And the controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri] string additionalParam, [FromBody] List<somemodel> models)
```

Obviously this works for my sample objects `somemodel` but you get the idea.

Comment: This works perfect. My controller code looks exactly like yours, but the code in the setup section is like this: Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/mycontroller/controllermethod?additionalParam=" + "test", productList); Is there any particular reason you added additional code in the setup section? I am pretty sure my productList automatically gets converted to Json when sent. In the debugger what I currently have seems to be working.

Comment: Yeah because I don't seem to have `PostAsJsonAsync` and nuget isn't allowing me to get it for some reason at the moment, I just added some code to get it working and to pass in the `json`, but it's basically the same thing!